# How to merge 2 Pandas Dataframes (that have been pivoted) together with hierarchical index on columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pivot-table

I have 2 dataframes obtained from the WHO API using JSON

here is the code I used to get the data:

```
import requests                 
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import read_html
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize   
import urllib2, json 
import html5lib

#Measles - Number of deaths of children < 5 by country & year
url = "http://apps.who.int/gho/athena/data/GHO/MORT_100.json?profile=simple&filter=COUNTRY:*;CHILDCAUSE:CH6"
response2 = urllib2.urlopen(url)
response_json2 = json.loads(response2.read())   
dfWHO2 = json_normalize(response_json2['fact'])
dfWHO2 = dfWHO2.loc[dfWHO2['dim.AGEGROUP']== '0-4 years']
WHOMeaslesChildhoodDeaths = dfWHO2.pivot('dim.COUNTRY','dim.YEAR','Value').astype(float)

#Measles First Dose Vaccination rate
url = "http://apps.who.int/gho/athena/data/GHO/WHS8_110.json?profile=simple&filter=COUNTRY:*"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
response_json = json.loads(response.read())
dfWHO1 = json_normalize(response_json['fact']).pivot('dim.COUNTRY','dim.YEAR','Value').astype(float)
WHOMeasles1stVaccRate = dfWHO1
WHOMeasles1stVaccRate = WHOMeasles1stVaccRate.loc[:,'2000':'2016']
```

This gives me 2 dataframes:
[image: Measles - Number of deaths of children]
&
[image: Measles First Dose Vaccination rate]

What I want is to get a dataframe at the end that looks approximately like this:
[image: Combined Rate and Deaths]

I'm not quite sure how to approach it.

I did an unstack:

```
temp1 = WHOMeasles1stVaccRate.unstack() 
temp2 = WHOMeaslesChildhoodDeaths.unstack()
temp1 + temp2
```

and that gave me 2 series which I then concatenated - but of course they did not have anything to separate the "rate" from the "deaths" So the output looked like this:

```
dim.YEAR  dim.COUNTRY                                         
2000      Afghanistan                                             10607
          Albania                                                    97
          Algeria                                                  1630
          Andorra                                                    97
          Angola                                                   1572
          Antigua and Barbuda                                        95
          Argentina                                                  91
          Armenia                                                    95
          Australia                                                  91
          Austria                                                    75
          Azerbaijan                                                 90
          Bahamas                                                    93
          Bahrain                                                    98
```

I realise I'm missing something in how to go about this - any help gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [swaplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html)

```
Newdf=pd.concat([WHOMeasles1stVaccRate,WHOMeaslesChildhoodDeaths],axis=1,keys=['Rate','Deaths']).swaplevel(1,0,axis=1).sort_index(1)
```

Comment: Brilliant Answer! Thank You - Worked perfectly! I'm going to have to read the docs on swaplevel to know how to use it better. Although it seems pretty simple once I looked at the example with just the concat. I'll also practice the concat a bit more - working out the options and being intimately familiar with them will be really good I think. But your example here has helped me immensly thank you!  Hope you don't mind - I linked in the docs pages to both of them for my own benefit for later when I am reviewing this

Comment: Thank you for the guidance - My python smack fu will improve over time.  I learn best by doing, but it has a bit of a steep curve.

Comment: Saw that literally as I posted it - so I quickly got rid of the ask.  Your profile says you are a data scientist - So Cool.  That is where I want to take my career - I am currently studying Data Science at Uni after work.   I've taken a bit of a career shift quite recently - I've been in the workforce for a good few years - mostly in IT customer service but just recently shifted into a Business Analyst role - focused in our companies Data Warehouse.  That's another steep learning curve!  Doing a lot with SQL - and database dimensions.  Thankfully a lot of the skills are tranferrable to this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168963/discussion-between-kiltannen-and-wen).

Comment: @kiltannen SQL is the one of the most popular language in this world , and if due with data, SQL skill is high priority.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 unpacking in a constructor.
This was for fun!  I'd use @Wen's answer.

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame({
    **{(k, 'Rate'): v for k, v in WHOMeasles1stVaccRate.items()},
    **{(k, 'Deaths'): v for k, v in WHOMeaslesChildhoodDeaths.items()},
})

ndf.iloc[:10, :10]

                        2000           2001          2002          2003         2004      
                      deaths  rate   deaths  rate  deaths  rate  deaths  rate deaths  rate
dim.COUNTRY                                                                               
Afghanistan          10580.0  27.0  14120.0  37.0  6891.0  35.0   225.0  39.0  367.0  48.0
Albania                  2.0  95.0      0.0  95.0     0.0  96.0     0.0  93.0    0.0  96.0
Algeria               1550.0  80.0   1616.0  83.0  1646.0  81.0  2567.0  84.0   38.0  81.0
Andorra                  0.0  97.0      0.0  97.0     0.0  98.0     0.0  96.0    0.0  98.0
Angola                1536.0  36.0   4643.0  65.0  6061.0  66.0  2238.0  52.0   36.0  52.0
Antigua and Barbuda      0.0  95.0      0.0  97.0     0.0  99.0     0.0  99.0    0.0  97.0
Argentina                0.0  91.0      0.0  89.0     0.0  95.0     0.0  97.0    0.0  99.0
Armenia                  3.0  92.0      3.0  93.0     3.0  91.0     3.0  94.0    3.0  92.0
Australia                0.0  91.0      0.0  92.0     0.0  94.0     0.0  94.0    0.0  94.0
Austria                  0.0  75.0      0.0  79.0     0.0  78.0     0.0  79.0    0.0  74.0
```